# vk api User authorization failed photos.saveWallPhoto

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Имеется следующий код, история в том, что все методы выполняются , кроме photos.saveWallPhoto

```
vk = vk.API(session)
w=vk.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=********,v=5.74)['upload_url']
print(w)
request = requests.post(w, files={'photo': open('image.jpg', 'rb')})
params = {'server': request.json()['server'],
          'photo': request.json()['photo'],
          'hash': request.json()['hash']}
vk.photos.saveWallPhoto(**params,v=5.74)
```

vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 5. User authorization failed: no access_token passed..

В чём может быть ошибка?

```
def post():
vk.wall.post(owner_id=*******,message =a.get() ,v=5.74)
message_entry.delete(0, END)
```

этот код работает, т.е проблема не в токене

Comment: токен есть? проверяли?

Comment: конечно есть., wallpost работает

Comment: там два вида токенов, один для группы один для пользователя,, это джаваскрипт? на каком языке это написано?

Comment: `const Group = new VK.Group(vk_credentials.group_token);
const User = new VK.User(vk_credentials.user_token);` вот так примерно, но это у меня на nodejs

Comment: Python///////////

Comment: у вас 2 токена? один для группы, другой для узера

Comment: Один, при помощи standalone приложения через oath. Мне нужно разместить пост в открытой группе от своего имени.